# Creating a multi tenant application using Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, yaml, multi-tenant

I am trying to create a multi tenant application using Symfony2.

Does anybody know how to select the database to connect to based on the domain the application is reached through? eg. company1.domain.com => db1, company2.domain.com => db2

I have found plugins that may help like sfMultiTenantPlugin, but all seem to have drawbacks.

I just need the parameters.ini file to have a different database_name value based on the domain.

Comment: I think I may have found a solution. http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/external_parameters.html .
This uses apache virtual host settings to pass the database name and password.

Comment: multiple databases *is not* multi-tenant database

Comment: sfMultiTenantPlugin is Symfony 1 not Symfony2

Comment: @Apot: storing passwords in environment variables is never a good idea. Just like chmod 777 to your web (document root) folder, is misguided.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this?
[Here](http://webcheatsheet.com/php/get_current_page_url.php)

Then use a switch to assign your connection variables.

```
case "company1.domain.com":
  $dbname = `db1`;
  etc.
```

(I have no experience with Symfony2, but it sounded like this was outside that.  I could be wrong.)
Hope this helps.

Comment: This example is exactly what I want to do in pure PHP but symfony separates the database connection into YAML files and ini file that are not script. Possibly I can choose the set of YAML files to load using this script.

Comment: Ah, I understand now.  I haven't dealt with Symfony2 or YAML files, so I'm no help.   I'd try loading the file like you said.